# PHP Repository pattern - update functionality

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am working on writing an update method, basically

```
class Entity {
 public $a;
 public $b;
}

class EnitityRepository {
 public function update(int $id, Entity $entity){
   $this->dao->update($id, $entity);
 }

 public function get(int $id){
   //does a look-up and returns an object of Entity
 }
}

class Dao {
  public function update(int $id, Entity $entity){
    $sql = "Update ABC";
    if(isset($entity->a) {
      $sql .= "set a = :a";
    }
    if(isset($entity->b) {
      $sql .= ", set b = :b";
    }
    $sql .= " WHERE id = :id";
  }
}
```

Now, in my dao, I want to update the record when there is no way to write conditional update (only update the values that are being set) as you don't know if a property on an object is set or not..and you can't just rely on `empty` or checking null as what if you really want to set the value as null.

would it be anti-pattern to use magic method `__get, __set, __isset` to refactor the `Entity` class like this?

```
class Entity {
  private $data = [];

  private $properties = [
      'a'      => true,
      'b'      => true,
  ];

  public function __set($name, $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->properties)) {
      $this->data[$name] = $value;
    } else {
      //throw exception
    }
  }

  public function __get($name) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
      return $this->data[$name];
    }

    return null;
  }

  public function __isset($name) {
    return isset($this->data[$name]);
  }

  public function __unset($name) {
    unset($this->data[$name]);
  }
}
```

Or is there any better way than passing an array instead of an object in Dao.

Comment: If you really need the magic methods , use them. Not sure if you really need them. But aren't you able to use a framework or something premade, like Laravel ? Or do you need to make it from scratch, or for a larger system ?